# SharePoint 2007 Powershell - Overwrite documents that require check out

Tags: 2007, powershell

I'm trying to build a PS script for a SharePoint 2007 which will loop through a list of site collections and update files within the 'Style Library' folder.

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $stream = $file.OpenRead()
    $done = $list.RootFolder.SubFolders["FolderName"].Files.Add($file.Name, $stream, $true)
    Write-Host $done.Name "Uploaded" -BackgroundColor Green
}
```

This loop tries to upload each file to the library but errors with the following message:

> Exception calling "Add" with "3" argument(s): "The file "..." is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes."

I'm struggling to find a way to programmatically check out documents, upload the new copy and then check that in. Is there any way of working around this?

Comment: Have you tried `$file.CheckOut()`

Comment: Thanks Amal, looping through the live files and running $file.CheckOut() seems to have worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CheckOut` as below

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file.CheckOut()
    $stream = $file.OpenRead()
    $done = $list.RootFolder.SubFolders["Hertel"].Files.Add($file.Name, $stream, $true)
    Write-Host $done.Name "Uploaded" -BackgroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amal, I had to run a seperate loop as $files in this scenario is actually a local library on the C:\ drive. Instead I ran a loop on the folder in the list and checked out each file, once that loop completed it then uploaded the files.

Comment: Sounds Ok. I believe you can manage it in a single loop. Anyway nice to hear issue is resolved.